# How can I make the slider which shows delete and other action come back to normal state once tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm implementing custom `editActionsForRowAt` actions for my `tableView` how do I make the slided cell come back to its normal state when tapped `done`, here is my code for the ViewController.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        list2.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    let done = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath) in

        let cell=tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell                
        cell.makeanimate()
    }

    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray        
    return [delete, done]
}
```

my `CustomCell` has the `makeanimate()` function. I want the cell to slide back to its normal position when I tap the `done` action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `setEditing(_:animated:)` function on the UITableView:

```
tableView.setEditing(false, animated: Bool)
```

You can read more on the function in Apple's documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614876-setediting

Comment: you mean `tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)`

Comment: @LeoDabus This is probably the desired effect, but whether it should be animated or not, is up to the person implementing, therefore I did not provide a value :-)